# Definition of degree of Frobenius of abelian variety and its dual

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties

How can I define the degree of Frobenius map and its **dual** of abelian variety ?

In algebraic curve case, we define degree of frobenius by corresponding field extension(For example, see Silverman's Prop. 2.11).

But in general abelian variety case, how can I define degree of isogeny except for $[n]$ map ? (Degree of $[n]$ map is defined as order of its kernel)

Once degree of frobenius is defined, can we define dual isogeny
$ \hat{Fr_p}$ by $[deg(Fr_p)]=Fr_p・\hat{Fr_p}$ in the same way as elliptic curve case?

Comment: “Order of its kernel” (or more precisely, *length* of its kernel as a [finite] scheme over the base field) still works.

Comment: Thank you. What is standard (or your recommended) texts or pdf about that ?

Comment: Another possible definition is (again) the degree of the function field extension. Scheme-theoretically, there’s also this one: an isogeny is a finite flat morphism, so it’s locally free of some rank, which is the degree (this recovers the other definitions). Unfortunately, I don’t know of a text I really like. I suppose the classics are Milne’s *Abelian varieties* (which is rather laconic) and Lang and Mumford (same title, I think, but it’s not schemes and it’s over an algebraically closed field). I don’t know how good the draft book of van der Geer-Moonen-Edixhoven on abelian varieties is.